# Function to refresh captcha, works on iPhone, not on desktop browsers

Tags: javascript, syntax, onclick, dom-events, onclicklistener

[Here](http://lorenzoraffio.com/index-3.php)'s my page where I have a function to refresh the captcha (if you click on "clicca qui" it should change the image). I'm 100% sure it worked some months ago and now it doesn't without me changing anything. The call to the function was `<a href="javascript: refreshCaptcha();">`. I noticed though that on iPhone it worked. So I thought it was a problem of some browsers that didn't accept the "javascript:" syntax. Then I changed it to `<a href="#" onclick="refreshCaptcha();return false;">` (as it is now, "live"). This changed nothing, still works (image changes) on iPhone, doesn't change on desktop browsers (tried with IE and Firefox).

Firebug console doesn't say anything.

What's happening?

Comment: Try `<a href="javascript:refreshCaptcha();">`, eg without space between `javascript:` and `refreshCaptcha()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not seem to find the reason but an empty string is returned when attempting to get the src like `document.images[4].src`. It only happens in FF so I am stumped more there. You can however access the image source using `.getAttribute("src")` and set it using `.setAttribute("src", "value")`.

Try the following code:

```
function refreshCaptcha(){ 
  var img = document.images['captchaimg'];
  imgSrc = img.getAttribute("src");
  newImgSrc = imgSrc.substring(0,imgSrc.lastIndexOf("?"))+"?rand="+Math.random()*1000;
  img.setAttribute("src", newImgSrc);
}
```

Also, please don't link to your site. It is okay to link to a fiddle but as soon as you make these changes on the site your question will no longer be of any help to the community.

Comment: On your page, in FF accessing the src as a property (the same way you would any other object) returns an empty string. Running `Object.keys(document.images['captchaimg'])` shows it is a property but for some reason it's value is a blank string. But in my example we are accessing the style attribute of the images tag. So we are accessing the string value that you can see in the HTML. I just don't know why the src attribute is different from the src property. You may make sure this new code works <=IE7 because they have some known mapping issues with the attribute and the actual object property.